# Incremental backups to Google Datastore

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

I'm trying to run Google BigQuery on data from the Datastore.
I've managed to create a backup, load it to BigQuery and query it, but the Datastore creates backups of its entire data - so unless I want to drop all of my old data and reload it (I don't), this is not an option.

I'm looking for a way to backup *some* of my entities and build an incremental database on the BigQuery service.

Comment: You can select which entity kinds you want to back up in the Datastore Admin - not just all of them: cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/datastoreadmin. If you mean you want to export selected entities of the same kind you'd need to perform queries and write them out to GCS manually.

Comment: You're right, however this isn't what I'm looking for. 
I'm looking for a way to backup some of the data (say, the last week or all new data since the last backup) and not all of it (which is what the console is offering now)

Answer (score 2):

So apparently this isn't an option for now - you can automate the backup process with cron jobs or open source solutions, but the backups are still for the whole data.

You can follow [this](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7428#makechanges) issue for updates on the issue or try the workaround suggested in [this](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12071#makechanges) issue (it didn't suit my project unfortunately)